# Convert known dateTime from one time zone to another

Tags: node.js

For example I have known date time for America Central Time: `03/05/2024 2:30 PM`
And I want to get to know what time will be on East time
I use `moment-timezone` module and have next code:

```
moment('03/05/2024 2:30 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A').tz('America/New_York').format('MMMM D | hh:mm A')
```

It works ok, but how to specify that `03/05/2024 2:30 PM` belongs to central time like `America/Chicago`

Answer (score 0):

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

moment.tz('03/05/2024 2:30 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A', "America/Chicago").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('MMMM D | hh:mm A')
```